# ‘abs’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

I''m working on GNURadio. Included `math.h` in my program but still get an error saying that `abs` was not declared in this scope.

Here is my header file.

```cpp
#ifndef INCLUDED_SLM_H
#define INCLUDED_SLM_H

#include "candidate_t.h"

namespace gr {
namespace uwspr {
class SLM {
public:
  // returns frequency drift according to the straight line model
  float slmFrequencyDrift(mode_nonlinear m_nl, float cf, float t);
  // generator of trajectory parameters for the straight line model
  bool slmGenerator(mode_nonlinear *m_nl);
  // initialize the generator
  void slmGeneratorInit();
  // index of current instances
  int current;
  SLM(){};
  ~SLM(){};
};
} // namespace uwspr
} // namespace gr
#endif /* INCLUDED_SLM_H */
```

Here is my code snippet for main function.

```cpp
#include "slm.h"
#include <math.h>

#ifndef DEBUG
#define DEBUG 1 // set debug mode
#endif
#include "debugmacro.h"

namespace gr {
namespace uwspr {
// Returns frequency drift (in Hz) due to the Doppler effect according to
// the straight line model, described in paper:
float SLM::slmFrequencyDrift(mode_nonlinear m_nl, float cf, float t)
// m_nl = trajectory parameters
// t = time, in seconds
{
  const float c = 1500.0; // sound speed (m/s)
  // sign of velocity vector
  float Sign = (((m_nl.V1 * t + m_nl.p1) * m_nl.V1 +
                 (m_nl.V2 * t + m_nl.p2) * m_nl.V2) > 0) *
                   2 -
               1;
  //
  double numerator = abs(m_nl.V1 * (m_nl.V1 * t + m_nl.p1) +
                         m_nl.V2 * (m_nl.V2 * t + m_nl.p2));
  // norm of connectiong vector (Eq. 16)
  double denominator =
      sqrt(pow(m_nl.V1 * t + m_nl.p1, 2) + pow(m_nl.V2 * t + m_nl.p2, 2));
  if (denominator == 0) {
    return 0.0;
  } else {
    // return -Sign;
    return -Sign * numerator / denominator * cf / c;
  }
}

// Generators of trajectory parameters for the straight line model
bool SLM::slmGenerator(mode_nonlinear *m_nl) {
  // control variables for init velocity
  const double V1_min = -2, V1_max = 2, V1_step = 1;
  const int nV1 = (V1_max - V1_min) / V1_step + 1;
  const double V2_min = -2, V2_max = 2, V2_step = 1;
  const int nV2 = (V2_max - V2_min) / V2_step + 1;
  // control variables for init position on y-axis
  const int p2_min = 50, p2_max = 850, p2_step = 200;
  const int np2 = (p2_max - p2_min) / p2_step + 1;
  // number of generated instances
  const int last = nV1 * nV2 * np2;
  // indices into the instances
  static int ip2, iV1, iV2;
  if (current == 0) {
    ip2 = 0;
    iV1 = 0;
    iV2 = 0;
  }
  if (current < last) { // not generated all instances?
    if (ip2 >= np2) {
      ip2 = 0; // reset index into the list positions
      iV1++;   // next horizontal velocity
      if (iV1 >= nV1) {
        iV1 = 0; // reset index into the list horiz. velocities
        iV2++;   // next vertical velocity
      }
    }
    // map horizontal velocity index to horizontal velocity (m/s)
    m_nl->V1 = iV1 * V1_step + V1_min;
    // map vertical velocity index to vertical velocity (m/s)
    m_nl->V2 = iV2 * V2_step + V2_min;
    // init coordinate on x-axis is always null
    m_nl->p1 = 0;
    // map y-axis coordinate index to y-axis coordinate (m)
    m_nl->p2 = ip2 * p2_step + p2_min;
    ip2++;     // next position on y-axis
    current++; // index of next instance
    return true;
  } else {
    return false; // reach the end
  }
}

void SLM::slmGeneratorInit() { current = 0; }

} /* namespace uwspr */
} /* namespace gr */
```

Comment: Since this is C++, try `#include <cmath>` and `std::abs`. Otherwise, you probably want `::fabs` (Or `std::fabs` with <cmath>)

Comment: @Artyer Thanks. That worked.

Comment: problem definitely unrelated to [tag:gnuradio-companion]. Removed that tag. Only very tangentially related to [tag:gnuradio], so removed that tag, too. Please be more conscious when using tags, and also, when asking about debugging of code not working, then it's kind of mandatory to produce a **minimum** compilable example of what goes wrong. `#include <math>`,  `int main() { float f = 2.0; return abs(f); }` would've been fully sufficient to test where the problem lies! Always try to reduce your problems to their core – makes solving them easier for you!

Comment: Also, I don't know why, but you explicitly specified `bash` syntax highlighting instead of C++ (`cpp`) highlighting... that's kind of counter-productive.

Answer (score 4):

`abs` is not defined in `<math.h>`. It can be found in `<stdlib.h>` and it is also defined as `std::abs` in `<cmath>`.

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, the `abs` function is defined in `<stdlib.h>` rather than `<math.h>`. (At least, that's the case since C++17). Try including `<stdlib.h>` or `<cstdlib>` and see if that fixes things.

Hope this helps!

Comment: No need to try or guess anything. Just [look it up](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs) and the header to include is handed to you on a silver platter.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you were using the C header file, `math.h`. The C standard already defined (the global scope) [`int ::abs(int)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/abs) to take an int and return an int, and this is defined in `stdlib.h`. The float version, [`double ::fabs(double)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fabs) is defined in `math.h`, which is the one you need to use.

C++ has overloads, so `std::abs` has [`double std::abs(double)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fabs) and [`int std::abs(int)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs) overloads. So you could just use the C++ header, `cmath`, and use `std::abs` (or `std::fabs` to prevent conversions) instead.